# How to use sendkeys function with promise chaining using selenium webdriverjs?

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, webdriverjs

This is the code:

```
 driver.get(url).then(function(){
         txtFnn = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(xpath));
         return txtFnn;
    }).then(function(){
           txtFnn.sendkeys("12345678");
    })
```

Error:

> TypeError: txtFnn.sendkeys is not a function

Comment: `txtFnn` variable contains `sendkeys` function??

Comment: is txtFnn a global variable? or in a scope that contains this code

Comment: does `driver.findElement` return a promise?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a lot because you don't supply much info, but from the code, I assume that `driver.findElement` returns a Promise ... so

```
driver.get(url).then(function(){
         return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(xpath));
    }).then(function(txtFnn){
           txtFnn.sendkeys("12345678");
    })
```

Does that work? If so, I'll explain where you went wrong in the first place, but if not, there's no point wasting time on explaining something comes from my assumptions

Answer (score 0):

your code can be simplified as:

```
driver.get(url);
txtFnn = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(xpath));
txtFnn.sendkeys("12345678");
```

can you try this and tell me if you are still getting the error? are you sure that the xpath is correct?